# Creating a function that differentiates rational functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbolic, argument-patterns

I want to create my own differentiation function `Derivada`. So, I already set some properties like:

```
Derivada[x_^(n_: 1), x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[n, x] := n*x^(n - 1)
Derivada[n_*x_, x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[n, x] := n
Derivada[Log[a_: E, x_], x_Symbol] := 1/(x*Log[a])
Derivada[Log[x_], x_Symbol] := 1/x
Derivada[f_, x_Symbol] /; FreeQ[f, x] := 0
Derivada[(a_?NumericQ) f_, x_Symbol] := a*Derivada[f, x]
Derivada[Exp[x_], x_Symbol] := Exp[x]
Derivada[a_^x_, x_Symbol] := a^x Log[a]
Derivada[u_Plus, x_Symbol] := Derivada[#, x] & /@ u
Derivada[u_*v_, x_Symbol] := u Derivada[v, x] + v Derivada[u, x]
Derivada[u_/v_, x_Symbol] := (Derivada[u, x]*v - u*Derivada[v, x])/v^2
```

I have a problem with rational functions.

The functions works for:

```
In[1224]:= Derivada[x/(x + 1), x]

Out[1224]= 1/(1 + x)^2
```

But the function doesn't works for:

```
In[1225]:= Derivada[1/(x + 1), x]

Out[1225]= Derivada[1/(1 + x), x]
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: just add the rule `Derivada[1 /v_, x_Symbol] := -Derivada[v, x]/v^2`?

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to improve the English a bit.  Please have a look, and check that you're happy with the edit.  Otherwise, you can always choose to rollback.

Comment: Note that the derivative of `x/(x+1)` is `-x/(1+x)^2 + 1/(1+x)`, NOT `1/(1+x)^2` as in your result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:** *Mathematica* manages to change the form of the underlying expression, and the expression no longer matches the pattern.

```
u_/v_ // FullForm
```

> ```
> Times[Pattern[u,Blank[]],Power[Pattern[v,Blank[]],-1]]
> ```

```
1/(x + 1) // FullForm
```

> ```
> Power[Plus[1,x],-1]
> ```

It also can not match the rule `Derivada[x_^(n_), x_Symbol]` as in the case of  `Power[Plus[1,x],-1]` the first argument is not the same `x` as the second argument in your rule (for a good reason).

**The solution:** You could keep on implementing a rule for every special case or you could implement a chain rule. Simplification of symbolic expressions is a field of research and sooner or later you will start publishing your methods in journals :)

**EDIT**

Just because it is a fun excuse to take the pattern matching to the limits, here is an implementation of 2 level chain rule:

```
Derivada[f:fh_[farg1___,g:gh_[garg1___,x_,garg2___],farg2___],x_]/;And[
Head[Derivada[g,x]]=!=Derivada,
Head[Block[{y},Derivada[f/.g->y,y]]]=!=Derivada
]:=Derivada[g,x]Block[{y},Derivada[f/.g->y,y]/.y->g]

Derivada[1/(x + 1), x]
```

[image]

Next step would be to make it recursive. It should check, if any of the arguments is also a function of x, and if it is possible to take a derivative of them. It is a deep rabbit hole.

Comment: Some suggestion to implement the chain rule?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.